# How to Delete checked row in MVC using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

How to Delete checked table row from Database in asp.net MVC using jquery
this is my code please help me with this.I have try the but this doesn't work if any one have suggestion please give me some.

```js
function saveOrder(data) {
        return $.ajax({
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            url: "/Bill/SaveOrder",
            data: data,
            success: function (result) {
                alert(result);
                location.reload();
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Error!")
            }
        });
    }
 var selectedValues = [];
            $.each($("#empsToDel"), function () {
                
                selectedValues.push({
                   ID = $("input:checked").val()
                })
            });
            var data = JSON.stringify({
            Delete:selectedValues
            });
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
   <th></th>
   <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Product.ProductName)</th>
 </tr>
 @foreach (var item in Model)
  {

 <tr id="new">
 <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="@item.ID" name="empsToDel" id="empsToDel" /></td>
  <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Product.ProductName)</td>
</tr>
}
</table>
<input id="saveOrder" type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="ok" />
```

### This is my controller

[image]

Comment: Why you have added only the controller code as a screenshot ?

Comment: When you debug, where specifically does this first fail?  You have several moving parts here, which one isn't doing what you expect?

Comment: There is JavaScript and html code also.

Comment: It's doesn't show error, but it's doesn't work either

Comment: It's doesn't pass data to the controller I think the problem is on client side.

Comment: @sandip: "It doesn't work" isn't a helpful description of the problem.  Consider this an opportunity to practice some basic debugging.  Does your view output the HTML code you expect?  Does your JavaScript code execute as expected?  Where do you call your `saveOrder` function?  What do you send to it?  Does it make the AJAX request as expected?  Does your controller action receive the expected parameters?  Where do you even create your `db` variable on the server?  Did you forget to commit a transaction?  What is the server's response to the client?  *Debug your code*.

Comment: @sandip: You have entirely misunderstood what the Stack Overflow community does.  Nobody here is going to do all of your work for you.  To better understand how this community can help you, you are encouraged to start here: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: @sandip, your question is not clear , anyway i will like to give some comments here .
you can first gather the selected row(i.e id's) and you can send them to controller as comma seperated string or as data, using Jquery(AJAX Request - Post JSON).  Inside Mvc controller you can use the JsonResult as action method instead of ActionResult and you have to add the [HttpPost] attribute to top of the action method.  Inside controller you can split the string by comma and loop through each id or you can pass list of ids to repository to bring all the entities at one hit and then delete then in batch

Comment: var ids = [1,2,3];
var idsStr = ids.toString() , 
this will convert the array to comma seperated, no need to use the stringy until or unless you are dealing only with id's , if you are dealing with objects on Mvc controller then you can go with Stringy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <table>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Product.ProductName)</th>
    </tr>
 @foreach (var item in Model)
  {

    <tr id="new'@item.ID'">
       <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="@item.ID" 
       name="empsToDel" id="empsToDel'@item.ID'" /></td>
       <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Product.ProductName)</td>
    </tr>
  }
</table>
<input id="saveOrder" type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="ok" />


$("#saveOrder").click(function ()
 {
          var selectedValues = new Array();
          $(".checkbox:checked").each(function () {
               selectedValues.push($(this).val());
           });

         var clientIdList = selectedValues.join();

       $.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("SaveOrder", "Bill")',
            data: { clientIdList: clientIdList },
            beforeSend: function () {                   
            },
            success: function (response) {
               alert(result);
               location.reload();
            },
            complete: function () {

            },
            error: function () {}
        });

 });
```

BillController.cs

```
    public ActionResult SaveOrder( string clientIdList = null)
        {
            if (clientIdList != "")
            {
                var clientIds = clientIdList.Split(',').Select(x => 
                         Int64.Parse(x)).ToArray();
            }
        }
```

Hopefully this will help for you.